# Not able to select autocomplete results in google places

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, google-places-api

I am using `google places API` in my ionic/cordova, angular based mobile app in android platform.

I am able to get search results from text field value using API but when i select an option by simply clicking on one of search results, the text box remains empty.
But when I press and keep holding the search result option for 2-3 secs, that option is selected.

It seems weird to me but it is happening.
`place_changed event` is not getting triggered on quick tap.
I really dont know what can be the cause of this issue? I have tried `Faskclick.j`s to eliminate 300 ms but that didnt work though I think this issue is not related to 300 ms delay.

**My code:**

```
 function initialize() {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
};
```

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

I used [ngMap](https://ngmap.github.io/) and [angular-google-places-autocomplete](https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete) together in the following example.

Hope it helps.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'google.places', 'ngMap'])

.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', 'NgMap',
 function ($scope, NgMap) {

  $scope.location = null;

  NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {
   console.log("getMap");
   $scope.map = map;
  });
  
  $scope.$on('g-places-autocomplete:select', function(event, place) {
   console.log('new location: ' + JSON.stringify(place));
   $scope.data = {
    lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
    lng: place.geometry.location.lng()
   };
   $scope.map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
   console.log($scope.data);
  });
 }
]);
```

```css
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>

  <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete/master/dist/autocomplete.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://rawgit.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete/master/dist/autocomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
  <ion-pane>
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
  <h1 class="title">Ionic map</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content class="has-header padding">
  
  <div class="item item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" g-places-autocomplete ng-model="location" placeholder="Insert address/location"/>
      </label>
      <button ng-click="location = ''" class="button ion-android-close input-button button-small" ng-show="location"></button>
  </div>
  <ng-map zoom="6" class="map">
    <marker position="{{data.lat}}, {{data.lng}}"></marker>
  </ng-map>
</ion-content>
  </ion-pane>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am afraid that didn't work. I used the same https://rawgit.com/wpalahnuk/ngAutocomplete/master/src/ngAutocomplete.js module but still on selecting the result, place_changed is not being triggered. I have to press and hold the result to make event fire. Its something related to android settings as same code works in browser.

Comment: Using angular-google-places-autocomplete instead of ngAutocomplete it works fine without need of any jQuery component

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find its solution but https://github.com/stephjang/placecomplete is a great plugin as work around :)